# Storing values in array

Tags: c

I need some help with my assignment. I need to create an array amounts to store five elements and then two arrays of five elements with the names dollars and cents. My problem is that I cant understand how to store the whole number part of each value in the amounts array in the corresponding element of dollars and the fractional part of the amount as a two-digit integer in cents(like if I input 2.75 - store 2 in dollars array and 75 in cents array).Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated! Thanks

This is what I have for now:

```
void main()
{
float amounts[5];
long dollars[5];
long cents[5];
int i = 0;

printf("Enter five monetary values separated by spaces:\n");
for(i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
scanf("%f", &amounts[i]);

for (i = 0; i<5; i++){

printf ("\ni=[%d],  dollars: %.2f, cents: %.2f\n", i, dollars, cents);
}
printf("\nYou entered the values: \n");

for(i = 0; i<5 ; i++)
printf("$%.2f\n", amounts[i]);
printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: You are missing the function that converts `amounts[i]` to `dollars` and `cents'. How would you determine the whole number of a floating point number? When you have the whole number, how can you determine the fractional portion? Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dollars[i] = (long)(amounts[i])` will truncate it, that is, remove the fractional part.

`cents[i] = (long)((amounts[i] - dollars[i]) * 100);` will give you the fractional part as an integer.